# Getting 406 when using OpenRasta HTTPEntity as return response?

Tags: dotnetopenauth, openrasta

In my handler code trying to return the redirect response with necessary openid headers/body to do the user-agent redirection to do the authentication, but when I set the return response with HTTPEntity in the Operation result I get 406 Not acceptable on the client? What is wrong with that? The following code is not complete and is of prototype quality!

Here is the my handler code:

```
private static OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
public OperationResult Get(string contentId)
{
   var response = openid.GetResponse();
   Identifier id;
   Identifier.TryParse("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id", out id);
   OutgoingWebResponse owr = openid.CreateRequest(id).RedirectingResponse;

   HttpEntity he = new HttpEntity(new HttpHeaderDictionary(owr.Headers), owr.ResponseStream);

   return new OperationResult.SeeOther { ResponseResource = he };

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't support IMessage / IHttpEntity / IResponse as return types at the moment, so that wouldn't work (but it would be great if it did, and it probably should).

The problem right now is that IRequest / IResponse (and associated entity bodies) are controlled by the hosting environment.

If you want it to work as is, I'd suggest creating a custom codec, register it on IHttpEntity (ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType().WithoutUri.TranscodedBy()) and use that codec to copy the headers and the body on the existing IResponse, which should take you 5 LOC.

I've open a bug on https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-core/issues/33 so we can move this into the core.

Comment: Thanks serialseb, I got it working with one exception the response has readonly headers so unable to set the headers on that is there any way we can do that?